# Express - passthrough of an image from another server

Tags: node.js, express

Apologies for a question that might seem like a duplicate but I wasn't able to adapt anything I could find to my needs. I have an end point that's hit from the front end, and I want that end point to respond with an image that will be shown inside  tag on the front end.

What am I doing wrong?

```
router.get("/getFace/:uname", function(req, res) {   

  var link_used = "https://lolapis/FacePicture/"+req.params.uname  
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: link_used,    
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer abcdefghijklmnopqrstu",
    },            
    success: function (data){                                   
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' });
      res.end(data, 'binary');
    }
  });

});
```

Query succeeds but I'm getting an empty 0kb image in response

Comment: Do you have to hit the endpoint in the server?
Couldn't you do <img src={API} > ?

Answer (score 0):

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end
From the documentation:

> Ends the response process. This method actually comes from Node core,
>   specifically the response.end() method of http.ServerResponse.
>
> Use to quickly end the response without any data. If you need to
>   respond with data, instead use methods such as **res.send()** and
>   **res.json()**.

Therefore:

```
success: function (data){                                   

      res.send(data);
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't work either. to be honest I have no idea why I need that writeHead line - why I can't just pass the data I receive (jpg image) and send it on?

Comment: @LucasSeveryn you are right. I forgot to remove. The send method should handle that for you. Could you tell me what response are you getting from the ajax request when success?